# wp-admin going directly to 404

Tags: wp-admin, htaccess

Recently, I was having an issue with all wp-admin pages.  I was able to login and see the dashboard, but every time I went to another admin page I would get a 404.

So after some searching, I started following some tips.

First was to look at the htaccess file.  Nothing seemed out of line there.  There is a htaccess.bk file and a normal htaccess.  Not sure what the bk is.  I deleted both to see what happens, nothing.

Next I changed the name of the plugin folder.  Now I'm not able to access anything in wp-admin not even able to login. I renamed the plugin folder to the orginal name again and still nothing.

I have a plugin called "WPS hide login" which changes the name of the login page.  Could that be the problem?  I'm still gravitating towards an htaccess file issue.

Comment: "I'm still gravitating towards an htaccess file issue.", but... "I deleted both to see what happens, nothing." - so what makes you think it's related to `.htaccess`? `.bk` would just be a "backup" file and not actively used.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a plugin called "WPS hide login" which changes the name of the login page. Could that be the problem?

Deactivate this plugin before you do anything else. It's unlikely that the issue is with htaccess, especially if you deleted it and nothing changed.

You might need to look if there is another htaccess file in the wp-admin folder.

Answer (score 0):

This might possibly be an issue with the URLs listed in the Settings under General. (If they don't match the URLs you're trying to use to get into Wp-Admin, then that can cause problems.)

Answer (score 0):

You can deactivate all plugins via the DB - you'll probably have phpMyAdmin or something from your hosting provider. Look for a field called `active_plugins` and turn that to NULL.

If you still have problems logging in then you will at least know it's an infrastructure issue. Try `/wp-admin/` and `/wp-login.php` check that's where the 404 actually is and you aren't being re-directed or something.

If you do get back in try flushing your permalinks and turning on the plugins one by one. You can check in an incognito window whether the issue returns after each plugin is reactivated